# Code Profiling Tools for Perl

Tags: perl, profiling

I need to test Perl Application ( File operation , Data base operation..etc ) .  I am looking for some profile tool for Perl code

is there any tools for Perl Code Profling like gprof in Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like with debugging, profiling is a task best done by the perl interpreter itself

[This website](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2004/06/25/profiling.html) will give you an overview of using the `-d:DProf` argument to the interpreter, and how to use it.

Comment: I ran into the exact same time problems the author described from your article.  I knew of gprof, and after trying to deal with my pain of a Perl script, felt a sense of relief and vindication when I read this article.  Thanks for the link.  I <3 Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 16):

Some people might suggest to use Devel::DProf as the most standard way, but if you will look closely it's actually pretty bad solution.

**The** best profiler for perl now is [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Devel::NYTProf).

If you'll google for it, you will see some presentations that show what it is capable of. And it's a lot.

Comment: nytprof is awesome. It's a bit bewildering at first but using it I got my genetic algorithm to run in 8 hours instead of 20 years!

Answer (score 7):

Krish: before you post questions, you should at least check the basic documentation. One way to look for something is `perldoc -q <something>`. The `-q` flag kicks off a keyword search through the FAQ.

So, for example, `perldoc -q profile`:

```
Found in /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pod/perlfaq3.pod
   How do I profile my Perl programs?
       You should get the Devel::DProf module from the standard distribution
       (or separately on CPAN) and also use Benchmark.pm from the standard
       distribution.  The Benchmark module lets you time specific portions of
       your code, while Devel::DProf gives detailed breakdowns of where your
       code spends its time.
```

And it goes on from there.