# perl scripting execution monitoring tools

Tags: perl, automation, perl-data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code Profiling Tools for Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078980/code-profiling-tools-for-perl)
>   [How can I track down CPU intensive requests in mod_perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194077/how-can-i-track-down-cpu-intensive-requests-in-mod-perl)

I am looking for a tool that can monitor the execution of Perl scripting based tool

and what exactly i am looking for is say we have lot of scripts, and they will be running .. very often but we want to know bottlenecks of perl code, so the where to optimize more and which routinues need to change , time taken by one script and when the thread is created etc..,

So that i can optimize the my code in  tool  , its hard to decode using perl debugger

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Aditya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm) - Powerful fast feature-rich perl source code profiler

Comment: Its already there in my list can i have few more similar kind of stuff

Comment: I think this one is the best profiler.

Answer (score 0):

[Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) isn't a profiler, it will only measure the total time taken by a code snippet, but sometimes that's all you need.

You're interested in other profilers?  The "Background" section of Devel::NYTProf mentions nine others:

```
Subroutine-level profilers:

* Devel::DProf        | 1995-10-31 | ILYAZ       it recommends NYTProf instead
* Devel::AutoProfiler | 2002-04-07 | GSLONDON
* Devel::Profiler     | 2002-05-20 | SAMTREGAR
* Devel::Profile      | 2003-04-13 | JAW
* Devel::DProfLB      | 2006-05-11 | JAW
* Devel::WxProf       | 2008-04-14 | MKUTTER

Statement-level profilers:

* Devel::SmallProf    | 1997-07-30 | ASHTED      FastProf is a fork of this
* Devel::FastProf     | 2005-09-20 | SALVA       NYTProf is a fork of this
* Devel::NYTProf      | 2008-03-04 | AKAPLAN
* Devel::Profit       | 2008-05-19 | LBROCARD    unmaintained
```

Really though, take Nikhil's advice, just use NYTProf.